# Email Errors with Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I have a PowerShell script that looks for a file in a folder and moves it to another folder, and renames the file with a date extension.
Like this:

```
    $a = "\\server\Users\Desktop\why agile.docx"
$f = "\\server\Users\desktop\Archive\why agile.docx"

Move-item $a $f

Function renameFile ($location, $filename, $extension)
{
    $d = get-date -uformat "%Y%m%d"

    $old = $location + $filename + $extension
    $new = $filename + "_" + $d + $extension
    rename-item $old $new
}

renamefile -location "\\server\Users\desktop\Archive\" -filename "why agile" -extension ".docx"
```

My question is:  How can I add to this script to email out any error messages, or if there are missing files, duplicate files or if the process fails for some reason (time out, etc...)?

Thanks,

Comment: [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5f7a9d63-6a37-4d98-b710-d76fde920a37/how-to-get-powershell-script-to-send-email-with-attached-file) might help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the other answer, you can wrap your  code in a try block and then in your catch block, email the errors.

Something like

```
try {
    rename file ...
}
catch [Exception] {
    Send-MailMessage ...
}
```

Comment: The try { } catch {} works perfectly.  On the 'try {move-item $a $f -ErrorAction stop} On the Catch { $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    Send-MailMessage -From my.name@mycompany.com -To my.name@mycompany.com -Subject " " -SmtpServer ' ' - Body $ErrorMessage"

Comment: my reputation isn't high enough to comment on your example of your answer so I'll comment here. Your try/catch statements should really be inside your function instead of wrapping your entire script in them. If you want to test the move and the rename and have one in a function and one not in a function, I would have a try/catch for each. Then write a function to send an email that's called. You can also pass in a message that explains that it failed on the move or the rename. You also want to follow the advice of clearing errors first.

Answer (score 2):

Clear the `$Error` automatic variable and set `$ErrorActionPreference` to `SilentlyContinue` before you start. [Send an e-mail](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) with the content of the `$Error` variable if it's not empty after you finished:

```psh
$Error.Clear()
$eap = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

renamefile ...

if ($Error) {
  Send-MailMessage -From $sender -To $recipient -Body ($Error -join "`n") ...
}

$ErrorActionPreference = $eap
```

For taking care of missing or duplicate files add appropriate checks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing.  I used the `try { } catch { }` and it works great.  Thanks to everyone for helping...it got me pointed in the right direction.  I'm an newbie with Powershell.

```
    try 
{
$a = "\\servername\Users\Desktop\agile.docx"
$b = "\\servername\Users\Desktop\Archive\agile.docx"


Move-item $a $b -ErrorAction stop

Function renameFile ($location, $filename, $extension)
{
    $d = get-date -uformat "%Y%m%d"

    $old = $location + $filename + $extension
    $new = $filename + "_" + $d + $extension
    rename-item $old $new
}

renamefile -location "\\servername\Users\desktop\Archive\" -filename "Agile" -extension ".docx"

}
Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    Send-MailMessage -From my.name@mycompany.com -To her.name@mycompany.com -Subject "Files Failed to Transfer to Archive Folder!" -SmtpServer smtp... -Body "The error message is: '$ErrorMessage'"
    Break
}
```